# $TEXMFHOME setting

Tags: environment-variables

I use texlive 2012 on ubuntu 12.04.
I wanted my `~/texmf` folder invisible, so I edited my `texmf.cnf` file which is in `/usr/local/texlive/2012` directory:

```
TEXMFHOME = ~/.texmf
```

I rebooted my computer and ran the command

```
kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME
```

which gave me `/home/myusrname/texmf`.
I checked `texmf.cnf` file again and it still had the line above.
And my `TEXMFHOME` really is `~/texmf` because I tested one of my `.sty` file under`/.textmf` and it did not work, while it still worked under `~/texmf`.

Should I change something else to change my `TEXMFHOME`?

Comment: There is no need to reboot ! Have you added a newline at the end of your `texmf.cnf` file?

Comment: Doesn't solve the `texmf.cnf` issue itself, but couldn't you just set `TEXMFHOME` in your `.profile`?

Comment: I tried on Mac OS X and it works; as Paul Gaborit says, there is no need to reboot. What's the answer of `env | grep TEXMF`?

Comment: Are you using the correct kpsewhich? Maybe the one from Ubuntu is interfering. What does "which kpsewhich" say?

Answer (score 24):

In Ubuntu:

```
$ kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME
/home/gpoo/texmf
$ export TEXMFHOME=$HOME/.texmf
$ kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME
/home/gpoo/.texmf
```

You can export the variable in your `.bashrc` file as:

```
if [ -d ~/.texmf ] ; then
    export TEXMFHOME=~/.texmf
fi
```

Comment: In your first listing the export is local to the current terminal. Is this correct?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: yes.

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of `-d ~/.texmf`?

Comment: In bash shell, it checks whether if the directory `~/.texmf` exists.  `~` is the user home directory.

Comment: On my system (Linux Mint 18), exporting TEXMFHOME as an env var does not change the output of kpsewhich. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 10):

The standard procedure you followed is correct. Edit

```
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf.cnf
```

to contain

```
TEXMFHOME = ~/.texmf
```

(better ensure a trailing return). There is no need to reboot.

However, if the output of `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME` is not `~/.texmf`, then probably you have set `TEXMFHOME` in your environment (probably in the `.bashrc` file). Check the output of

```
env | grep TEXMF
```

to see if this is the case. If it is, then you have to find where the variable is being set and remove it.