# Place my packages in my own folder

Tags: packages, installing

I want to create my own packages and classes. I know how to install them ([Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te)) but what if I don't want to put them in my TeX home directory ?

I want to add a directory somewhere on my computer to regroup all the files I need (packages, bibliography, logo ...) but I want to place it in a specific place to find it more easily (for me at least). How can I do it (if it's possible) ?

Comment: Which operating system are you using? You could set a symbolic link to your `~/texmf/tex/latex/` directory such that the packages are at the right place, but you can access them more easily.

Comment: Do you need both your tex home directory and this new folder? Otherwise you could change the tex home folder to your new location.

Comment: @Tiuri I use Linux (Ubuntu). Is it the only way ? (just to know, this one is good)
I have another question : when I execute `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME` I obtain a certain location (~\texmf) but I don't have this folder ??

@samcarter I suppose I need both but I'm not sure

Comment: @samcarter has described an alternative way. To your other question: By default, TeX looks for packages in ~/texmf. If this directory doesn't exist, it just skips it. But one can, at any time, create it and store packages there when needed, and then these packages are automatically included.

Comment: @Tiuri if I understand (English is not my friend) I can create ~\texmf and put my packages in this folder and then create a symlink. Or I can say to LaTeX to look for packages in my own folder. Is it true ?

Comment: Yes, I think that's two possibilities. I'll write the symlink solution with some explanations as a solution once I'm back on my laptop.

Comment: Ok thanks. For the second possibility, do you think I could do as here : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71469/texmfhome-setting ?

Comment: On Linux, the symlink solution definitely works. On Windows, it does not, because the link is merely an instruction to the Windows file Explorer. Although there is a way to do "hard links" in Windows, it is very risky, and will cause problems if you move things or create a zip archive with the link in it. So, don't do it.

Comment: On Windows one could use MicTeX, which allows multiple custom folders as far as I know (never used it myself …)

Comment: Update: TeX Live 2017 now also supports multiple `TEXMF`folders, see e.g. https://www.preining.info/blog/2017/06/tex-live-2017-released/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are excellent discussions on TeX.SE on how and where to store own LaTeX packages locally. In short:

- You need to store the files in the specific folder structure `texmf/tex/latex/mystuff`, where LaTex will look for `texmf` at some specific place, on Ubuntu with TeXLive usually `~/texmf`. [Continue reading](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1138/103046)
- You can change the location of this `texmf` folder, e.g. to `~/.texmf` (such that it will not be displayed in the file browser). [Continue reading](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71469/103046)

However, your own package files will always need to be in this nested folder structure, and you might wish your packages folder to be somewhere else near your other LaTeX files. So here is a **solution that works on Ubuntu** (and other Unix-like operating systems), but not on Windows.

Your folder structure is like this:

- `~/texmf/tex/latex/mystuff`, from where the packages are included in your LaTeX documents
- `~/Documents/coding/mystuff` (or similar), where you want to edit and manage your package files

The idea is to create a symbolic link ([excellent introduction](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/ln/) in German) such that the `mystuff` directory in one of the two places links to the other place. You can then access and edit the very same files using both paths.

So to create a symbolic link ([read more](https://askubuntu.com/a/843741)), simply execute one of the two following commands in a terminal:

- `ln -s ~/texmf/tex/latex/mystuff ~/Documents/coding/mystuff`
- `ln -s ~/Documents/coding/mystuff ~/texmf/tex/latex/mystuff`

You first specify the source directory and second location and name of the link. Thus, using the first line, `mystuff` is stored in `texmf` with a symbolic link in `Documents`, while using the second line gives it the other way around.

Comment: +1 nice comprehensive answer. The last solution works especially nicely for those of us with multiple computers. My local `texmf` is in Dropbox and linked like this.