# Place my own custom package in a different folder

Tags: packages, windows, links

I have made my own LaTeX package, which I want to store in a different folder then where the main .tex file is. Like so:

```
/folder/latex_settings/preamble.tex
                      /custom_latex_library.sty
/folder/week1/main.tex
```

I've tried to make a preamble.tex in which the packages are imported. This however doesn't solve my problem. I have done some research with this [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372945/place-my-packages-in-my-own-folder). In that solution, it uses symbolic links which do not work with Windows according to the solution. Is there any other way, preferably without creating symbolic links? This, because I work with several people on this project and don't want to create links everywhere if there is a solution without using links.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't have to be dealing with paths (symbolic or not). You have to write `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME` in a command line and place your package in the folder it tells you. Follow [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1138/140456) for a step by step solution

Comment: If you use TeX Live, you can have a look at the auxtree feature.